# invisible rect to handle rollover / rollout of a group

Tags: apache-flex

Is this the most efficient way to listen to mouse events on the background of a group?

```
<s:Group width="200" height="100" rollOver="group1_rollOverHandler(event)" rollOut="group1_rollOutHandler(event)">
    <s:Rect width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor alpha="0"/>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>
</s:Group>
```

seems pretty minimal, but alpha = 0 is not the most efficient thing out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm listening for `mouseDown` and `mouseUp` on a `Group` with nothing in it (for dragging) and it's working just fine.  A quick test with `rollOver` and `rollOut` reveals those events to be fired as expected.

I'd do this as it avoids having a fill with `alpha=0`:

```
<s:Group
  width="{width}"
  height="20"
  rollOver="_onRollOver(event)"
  rollOut="_onRollOut(event)"/>
```

EDIT:  Realized I forgot to directly address the question.  Narf!
To the best of my knowledge this is the most efficient way to listen for mouse events on a `Group` since we are not drawing anything at all, ever by using an empty `Group`.

Comment: fascinating - makes total sense and am not sure why I ever came up with the rect idea. Oh well - thank you for your help ;-)